# How to extract strings at particular position while using os.sep?

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy

I am using this code in ArcGIS environment to extract the file path of geodatabases in multiple folder.

```
gdbpath = path.split(featureclass)[0]
pathname = gdbpath.split(os.sep)
print pathname

Result:
['D:', 'QAQC', 'Imagery', 'GeographyScan', 'Chile', 'SNGM_Chile_Topography.gdb']
['D:', 'QAQC', 'Imagery', 'GeologyScan', 'Chile', 'Gloria', 'CODELCO_Chile_AlterationMap.gdb']
['D:', 'QAQC', 'Imagery', 'GeologyScan', 'Chile', 'Gloria', 'CODELCO_Chile_GeologicalMap.gdb']
['D:', 'QAQC', 'Imagery', 'GeologyScan', 'Chile', 'Gloria', 'CODELCO_Chile_SurfaceExplorationMap.gdb']
```

From this result i want the fourth string (GeographyScan, GeologyScan) alone to do further process. Is it possible to extract this ?

Comment: You can keep the paths as they are, and access the 4th element where that's needed, or you can `fourths = [ x[3] for x in paths ]`

Comment: Sorry for being naive. But, do i have to declare fourths = [ x[3] for x in pathname ] as a separate line ? Tried that it says "String index out of range"

Comment: It's actually not clear what your input is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.  The first two lines are to reassemble your string.  The result is not generalized for all paths to the gdb, but only gets the position desired.

```
>>> p = ['D:', 'QAQC', 'Imagery', 'GeographyScan', 'Chile', 'SNGM_Chile_Topography.gdb']
>>> pth = "".join(["{}/".format(i) for i in p])[:-1]
>>> pth
'D:/QAQC/Imagery/GeographyScan/Chile/SNGM_Chile_Topography.gdb'
>>> # Now that it is reassembled for testing path separators, split the string
>>> ps = os.path.split(pth)[0]
>>> sub = ps.split("/")
>>> sub[3]
'GeographyScan'
>>> sub
['D:', 'QAQC', 'Imagery', 'GeographyScan', 'Chile']
>>> s = "/".join((i) for i in sub[:4])
>>> 
>>> s
'D:/QAQC/Imagery/GeographyScan'
```

If you just want the 3rd slice, then just get it, if you want the path up to and including you can just rejoin.

I have presented this in a verbose form so the procedure can be seen.  Obviously you can assemble the necessary shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Worked perfectly.